# Javascript only executing the first time when sending XHR requests with Remote true in form_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, form-for

I have a form for filtering products, and want to change by AJAX the results on the partial for results:

```
<%= form_for :pin, url: filter_path, method: :get, remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.radio_button :category, category %>
      <%= f.range_field :max_value , type: "range", value: "1000", min: "1", max: "1000" %>
      <%= f.submit "Buscar", class: "margin_top width100" %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, I respond to JS with a partial:

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render "filter_products" }
    format.html {render "index"}
  end
```

And lastly, on my `filter_products.js`, I change the partial with the new results:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newProducts = '<%= j(render partial: "product_list", collection: @pins) %>';
    $("#product-list").replaceWith(newProducts);
});
```

Where product_list is my partial with the new products:

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <%= render partial: "product_card", locals: {pin: pin} %>
<% end %>
```

**Its working OK, but only the first time I submit the form. The second time on, its sending XHR requests with 200 responses, but it's not replacing the old products on the view.**

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The replaceWith wasn't working, instead, I used `html`.

```
 $("#product-list").replaceWith(newProducts);
```

to

```
 $("#product-list").html(newProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because Rails Turbolinks. Try to add https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

From documentation:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Add it to your JavaScript manifest file, in this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```